# Laravel - Eloquent Joins

Tags: laravel

I'm just starting to learn laravel and its orm system, Eloquent.  I'm not sure how to correctly join tables with it though.  I have 3 models: User, Account, AccountType and I don't know how to join Account with Accounttype.

Account Model Class:

```
public function accounttype(){
    return $this->hasOne('AccountType');
}
```

This is to pass accounts information to view:

```
$accounts = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->accounts;
$accounts->load('accounttype');
return View::make('accounts.accounts')->with('accounts', $accounts);
```

That will give the following error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'accounttypes.account_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `accounttypes` where `accounttypes`.`account_id` in (1, 2, 3))

It should be pulling by id in the accounttypes table not account_id.  I can list the user accounts just fine, I just don't know how to join the accounttypes table to the account table.

Database Tables:

Users

- id
- username
- password
- timestamps(updated_at / created_at)

Accounts

- id
- name
- user_id
- accounttype_id
- timestamps

AccountTypes

- id
- name

Each user can have more than one account and each account will have an account type.

Comment: It depends on your `database`, show your database tables for each `Model`s.

Comment: How your `accounts` and `accounttype` related and does a `user` has more than one account ?

Comment: Each user will have one or more accounts and each account will have a type.

Comment: try `belongsTo` instead of `hasOne`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `User` model:

```
public function accounts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Account');
}
```

In `Account` model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

public function accountType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('AccountType', 'accounttype_id', 'id');
}
```

In `AccountType` model:

```
public function accounts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Account', 'accounttype_id', 'id');
}
```

Then in your Controller:

```
// This will return a user with all accounts ($user->accounts will be collection)
$user = User::with('accounts')->find(Auth::user()->id);
```

Or:

```
$user = User::with('accounts.accountType')->find(Auth::user()->id);

// You may pass the $user as well and then loop the $user->accounts in view
return View::make('accounts.accounts')->with('accounts', $user->accounts);
```

In your `view` you may loop to get all accounts like:

```
@foreach($accounts as $account)
    {{ $account->name }}
    {{ $account->accountType->name }}
@endforeach
```

Since `$user->accounts` is a collection so you may either run a `loop` or specifically get an account using something like this:

```
{{ $accounts->first()->name }}; // Get first one's name
{{ $accounts->get(0)->name }}; // Get first one's name
{{ $accounts->get(1)->name }}; // Get second one's name
{{ $accounts->last()->name }}; // Get last one's name
```

if you pass the `$user` instead of `$accounts` like this:

```
return View::make('accounts.accounts')->with('user', $user);
```

Then change the loop as well, like this:

```
@foreach($user->accounts as $account)
    {{ $account->name }}
    {{ $account->accountType->name }}
@endforeach
```

You can make sure if that user has accounts in the `view` before you start the loop, like:

```
@if($user->accounts->count())
    // Loop Here
@endif
```

Comment: Quick question, should: $user = User::with('accounts')->find(Auth::user()->id); be $user = User::with('accounts.accounttype')->find(Auth::user()->id); to reduce the query count?

Comment: Yes, you may get the `accountType` like that way.